# Is it multilanguage site made using WordPress ? Can I deduct it from the URL?

Tags: wordpress, joomla, web, content-management-system

I have this web site URL: http://www.erusma.org that is a multilanguage website, infact opening this URL I obtain the following address: **http://www.erusma.org/en/default.html**

Looking at the source code of the page it's not clear what CMS is used to build this website.

I need to know this information and I think that I can infer it from the previous address that is in the form: **sitename/language/page.html**

Could they have used WordPress? Looking in this tutorial seems that the previous address form is a multilanguage WordPress site that use a rewrite rule but I am not sure

http://gabrieleromanato.com/2013/07/wordpress-gestire-gli-url-nei-plugin-multilingua/

What do you think? Can I deduct from the address, what CMS is used? Or it could be in Joomla? To what extent would my deduction be precise?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how it works with multilanguage plugin, but the easiest way to check if site is based on Wordpress is to add /wp-admin to site's URL.

Ex:
you want to check if http://www.spidersweb.pl/ is WP. Add /wp-admin, so the URL is: http://www.spidersweb.pl/wp-admin

AFAIR to check if site is based on Joomla add /administrator

Your site uses neither WP nor Joomla, or this multilanguage plugin changes default login URL.